# Обращение к определенному элементу DOM дерева [JQuery]

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

**Имеем:**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
            <form>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <label>Simple text 1</label>
                        <input type="text" name="inp1" value="Text 1">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label>Simple text 2</label>
                        <input type="text" name="inp2" value="Text 2">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label>Simple text 3</label>
                        <input type="text" name="inp3" value="Text 3">
                    </li>
                <ul>
                <input class="getInfoButton" type="button" value="Get Value">
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Соль:** Нужно получить значение, третьего `<input>`, имея на руках такой селектор `$(".getInfoButton")`

Нужно решить эту задачу оптимально, тобишь если я потом захочу в DOM дереве переместить третий `<input>` на несколько `<li>` ниже (добавив между третьим и вторым `<li>` еще пункты)

**P.S** Если такое решить невозможно, тогда как я понимаю нужно писать свою функцию

Comment: Что-то типа такого может быть? `$('.getInfoButton').prev().children('input[type=text]').eq(3);`

Comment: _"... если я потом захочу в DOM дереве переместить третий `<input>`..."_ - нужно всегда обращаться к третьему по счету или к этому конкретно, независимо, каким он будет по счету в будущем?

Comment: @lexxl А этого мы не знаем) он может быть 7-ым а может быть и 27-ым

Comment: @MaximPro, _Обращение к определенному элементу_, а как определять какой элемент нужен так и не написали, то третий, то седьмой

Comment: @MaximPro я спрашиваю, что надо найти - третий элемент в будущем, или тот, что третий сейчас =) от этого зависит, к чему привязываться - к порядковому номеру или имени/классу/айди

Comment: @Grundy Да не очевидно написал, но видимо по атрибуту

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Выбирайте по идентификатору: `$('#id3')` (но нужно будет добавить этот идентификатор соответствующему `<input id="id3">`), или же просто выбирайте по имени `$('[name="inp3"]')`.

Ну или в вашей задаче:

`$('.getInfoButton').prev().find('[name="inp3"]')`

Только я не понимаю зачем отталкиваться именно от этого селектора, но дело ваше.

Comment: Почему от этого селектора? Потому что от него будет произведен щелчек мыши =)

Comment: @MaximPro, все равно не понимаю, клик можно по этому элементу сделать, а данные получить с любых других.

Comment: Хмм а действительно, что-то я совсем дичь задаю

Comment: @MaximPro, кое что поменял в коде, такой точно должен работать.

Comment: Про find не слышал))) Я видимо это и искал)
И насчет `children()`, в моем коде мы не можем написать так `$('.getInfoButton').prev().children('input[name=inp3]')` т.к это работает для одной вложености, а не для нескольких, верно?!

Comment: @MaximPro, да, `children()` будет не корректно работать, ну в `find()` сработает как надо, в своем примере уже исправил.

Comment: Принимаю ваш ответ =) Думаю так будет честно!

Comment: @MaximPro, что вы ожидаете от этого кода, если несколько элементов с классом _.getInfoButton_ на странице?

Comment: @Grundy, если несколько элементов с этим же классом, то выберется только первый попавшийся, остальные будут проигнорированы. А вообще, конечно принцип выборки надо менять, это не хороший пример.

Answer (score 3):

Вот, что Вам поможет:

```
$('.getInfoButton').prev().find('input[type=text]').eq(2);
```

Подробнее:

`$('.getInfoButton')` - Сам элемент
`.prev()` -> шаг наверх по DOM
`.find('input[type=text]')` -> отбираем в нем `input[text]`
`.eq(2)` -> берем 3-й элемент

Comment: Хороший ответ, для новичков с описанием методов

Comment: @MaximPro, на самом деле не очень. если несколько элементов с классом _.getInfoButton_ на странице

Comment: @Grundy для этого можно использовать `$(this)`

Comment: @MaximPro, откуда будет брать `$(this)` если в данном контексте нигде не указано про обработчик события, в принципе это указано только в ответе @mix

Comment: @Grundy Так я сделаю этот обработчик событий =)

Comment: @Grundy Вы писали выше что пример не очень, то напишите который более правильный с вашей точки зрения, интересно узнать

Comment: @MaximPro, уже написал в комментариях к ответу `@mix`, если его две строчки заменить на мою одну - будет более менее, хотя тоже не очень. потому что я выбираю именно третий по счету а не тот у которого например атрибут какой-то или класс

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".getInfoButton").click(function(){
    var selector = $('input[type="text"]')[2];
    console.log($(this).parent().parent().find(selector).val());
});
```

Вот решение задачи по вашим требованиям, но это называется никак иначе, как "говнокод". Задайте лучше тегам классы или идентификаторы и выбирайте основываясь на них.

Comment: что-то перемудрили: нашли конкретный элемент, _selector_ - почему сразу у него _value_ не взять? да и два parent - не нужно, первый будет указывать на форму и этого достаточно

Comment: @Grundy так будет яснее для автора.

Comment: думаешь? мне кажется это еще больше запутает :)

Comment: Хотел написать как у вас код с подписью **такое не надо**

Comment: @Grundy думаю, иначе зачем в мануале именно так написано!? к тому же одним парентом ты не найдешь 3-ий инпут.

Comment: `$(this).parent().find('input:eq(3)')` вот так находится

Comment: @Grundy у меня же не так написано!? я сам такой код не пишу, данный код для **решения конкретной задачи по конкретным тебованиям**

Comment: @mix вон выше люди написали да и @Grundy про метод `find()`

Comment: @mix, нет, не так. третий инпут на странице может не быть третьим инпутом внутри формы

Comment: @MaximPro я не буду против, если вы не будете использовать мой вариант, но, тем не менее, с поставленной задачей мой вариант справляется.

Comment: @Grundy даже так.. значит не уловил суть вопроса полностью

Comment: @mix, кстати интересно, но я не знаю как отработает _find_ если ему передать dom элемент, а не строку

Comment: @mix справляется оно верно, больше всего меня пугают такие конструкции `prev().prev().prev().prev().prev()` или `next().next().next().next().next()` Нецелесообразно как-то

Comment: @MaximPro, на самом деле им можно передавать параметр, и количество вызовов сократится до 1, но это только если искать на одном уровне

Comment: @MaximPro если вас пугают данные конструкции, это еще не значит, что они нецелесообразны. Скажу вам, что нет ничего страшного в `parent().parent()`, если использовать это разумно.

Comment: @Grundy Пытался передавать параметры, но все тщетно, не работает у меня)

Comment: @MaximPro, тут надо смотреть что именно пытались и на какой разметке